# PowerApps: clearing an input field when returning to a page

Tags: powerapp

I have an app where the primary screen is a search screen. It contains a gallery with part numbers and a brief summary of each. The screen also has a Text Input field for entering a part number.

When the screen is initially loaded, all parts are loaded into the gallery. As the user begins to enter a part number, the gallery results get smaller and smaller. Eventually, the user sees the part number they desire in the gallery and they will click on a navigation icon to load a second screen. The second screen is the detail screen which contains (obviously) the details about the selected part.

I have a button on the second screen which users can press to cancel out and return to the previous (search) screen. The OnSelect property is:

**Navigate(scrSearch, ScreenTransition.None)**

The app will return to the previous screen, but it retains the part number (or partial part number) in the Search field. Is there a way to clear that field whenever the screen is loaded? I've been fighting the whole notion that I can't set focus on (literally) the only field on the screen, but does PowerApps force the user to click on the field (to gain focus) then click the X (to clear the data) as well?

Thanks,

gpence

UPDATE: I've tried using the OnVisible property and setting the value for the Text Input to "", but I haven't had any luck with that concept. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *reset* property to empty field. I'm using it and it works.

[More Info Here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/How-to-clear-a-Text-Input/td-p/3545)